# MATCH AGAINST IN BOOLEAN MODE MySQL weird behavior

Tags: mysql, match

I try to fetch some data matching exactly 2 or more required words in two columns (not necessary both of 2 columns) but when the one of the word consists 3 letters the matching score is 0.

I have already set innodb_ft_min_token_size=1 and ft_min_word_len=1 (I use innodb engine), I have already reindex my table, I restart mysql but the problem persist.

I also try to seperate fulltext indexes for each column (because I use + (so, words are required)) but without expected results

```
WHERE MATCH (`text`, `alter_text`) AGAINST ('+the +article' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0
```

for separated columns

```
WHERE  (MATCH (`text`) AGAINST ('+the +article' IN BOOLEAN MODE) + MATCH (`alter_text`) AGAINST ('+the +article' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) > 0
```

If I replace the word 'the' with 'then' everything works ok (replacing first the 'the' with 'then' in database table records)

Without +, everything works ok even with 1 letter like "t", but is crucial for me to work with +

So my main question is
Why don't I get the expected results ?

Minor question
Does MATCH (`text`, `alter_text`) AGAINST ('+the +article' IN BOOLEAN MODE) return positive score in case both of 'text' and 'alter_text' columns contains 'the' and 'article' at the same time? or its enough one of them columns ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is happning because of default stopwords (the is default stopword). To rectify it execute following two statements on your db.

```
 CREATE database_name.table_name (
  `value` VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

SET GLOBAL innodb_ft_server_stopword_table = 'database_name/table_name';
```

after that drop fulltext index from table AND recreate it.